# Flutter TextEditingController clear wont reset the error message

Tags: flutter, dart

I using the flutter form autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction to do validate if textfield didnt fill in.

How to make the validate error message hide when submit the form and reset the textfield again?

Below is my code to demo the my problem, after fill in the textfield and press submit. The red error message also show up which is not UX friendly.

DartPad link: https://dartpad.dev/d26c3f57be04acaafae2ee127a688e3f

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create a Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController taskController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: taskController,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                // otherwise.
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar and reset
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                  taskController.clear();
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you dont want to show an error message at all?

Comment: don't forget to use `dispose()` when you use texteditingcontroller at statefull widget

Comment: @KetanRamteke, only hide the error message after submit the form, when user didnt fill in and press button still need to show

Comment: @GilangPratama I thought Flutter will auto dispose the texteditingcontroller, it wont?

Comment: my previous comment is about when we close our page. btw, I always using state management for form validation because sometimes the text helper force the textfield be smaller when I made a thextfield height width container.

Comment: @GilangPratama what kind of  state management for form validation you use, can share some example?

Comment: I'm using BloC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `InputDecoration` to toggle the `errorStyle` and achieve the desired result.

Output:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create a Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController taskController = TextEditingController();
  bool hideError = false;
  bool first = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
              controller: taskController,
              decoration: hideError && !first
                  ? InputDecoration(
                      errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                      )
                  : null,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  print(value);

                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  hideError = false;
                  first = false;
                });
              }),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                // otherwise.
                setState(() {
                  hideError = true;
                });
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar and reset
                  
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')));
                  taskController.clear();
                  
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can make it also show error on the first click on button if textfield havent focus and type anything yet?

Comment: didn't get what you are trying to achieve. Can you rephrase it with more details?

Comment: current behavior emulates the one that you have described in the question, I don't see the need to complicate it anymore and I don't see how it will improve the overall user interface. It's excessive experimentation imo.

Comment: Hi, by testing your code, it wont validate the text field when click the submit button at very first beginning

Comment: updated code. check out. And if you found this answer helpful don't forget to upvote and accept. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
validator: (String value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return ' ';
          }
          return null;
        },
```

Do this, by returning an empty String you can still see the text Field red.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to show error message then simple delete the validator.

```
validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
```

remove this from your code !!

Comment: no, cannot delete I still want validate the field. I dont want to show the error when the moment submit the form only